# Web Page's Scrollbar Is Missing and Div Unable To Extend To Bottom

Tags: jquery, html, css

Can anyone explain why, number one, my scrollbar is missing, and two, why the part that scrolls is not extending down to the bottom? The website is question is [here](http://ideasandpixels.com/new_site/portfolio/view_project/athletebuzz). Thanks!

Comment: do you want the scroller to come for the entire page? or just that div where you have long content sir? just remove these from your body css height min height and overflow you would be see the scollbar

Comment: The gap at the bottom seems arise because there is a height difference between your project_wrapper div and the body, but I can't find any margin,padding,border,etc. styles to account for it.

Answer (score 0):

Removing `height:100%` from the HTML tag fixes the space at bottom.

For scrolling in the content, you need to set a height for that container, and define a scroller. So add to `#project_wrapper #center_holder {height:100%; overflow:scroll;}`

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to use a `y overflow:` css property, which doesn't exist. Use `overflow-y: auto;` in stead.

However just changing that still leaves the <div> scaling to the height it needs and the containing div cutting it off. There's something funky going on with the various div's on your page. You could fix it by setting the height of the div you want to scroll explicitly, but that won't scale for different browser window sizes. A better solution would be to look at the containing div's and simplifying the structure.